# Determine the constant coefficient linear ODE which has general solution $y = C_1e^{2x} + C_2\sin(3x) + C_3\cos(3x) + C_4x\sin(3x) + C_5x\cos(3x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the constant coefficient linear ODE which has general solution
$y = C_1e^{2x} + C_2\sin(3x) + C_3\cos(3x) + C_4x\sin(3x) + C_5x\cos(3x)$

I am not really sure what this question is asking? am i supposed to find $C_1,\ldots,C_5$? if so, how do I do that

Comment: I think some important information is missing here. Are there any initial conditions?

Comment: @Alex Chavez : The question is not to find $C_1,\ldots,C_5$. The question is to find a linear ODE. This ODE must have the general solution on the form given. Since it is a general solution, it must agree with the ODE that you have to find, any values of $C_1,\ldots,C_5$. First you have to find what must be the order of the ODE. Second, to write the pattern of the ODE of that order. This pattern includes some coefficients. Third, you have to find the values of those coefficients.

Comment: Haven't you been taught to tell the order of an ode from its general solution? That's why I posted my first comment before the answer was posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

The characteristic equation of the linear ODE has roots $2$, $3i$ and $-3i$, being the last two of multiplicity two. Then, the characteristic equation of the ODE is
\begin{align}
(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3i)^2(\lambda+3i)^2&=0\\
(\lambda-2)(\lambda^2+9)^2&=0\\
\lambda^5-2\lambda^4+18\lambda^3-36\lambda^2+81\lambda-162&=0
\end{align}

Comment: so  the answer would be: 

$y^{(5)} -2y^{(4)} + 18y^{(3)} -36y'' +81y-162$ ?

Comment: $y^{(5)}-2y^{(4)}+18y'''-36y''+81y'-162y=0$